# How to change initdb own messages localization?

Tags: postgresql, windows, localization

When I initialize a cluster the messages produced by `initdb` are in French.
I tried the following options :

```
--locale=en_US
--lc-messages=en_US    
--no-locale
--locale=C
```

`initdb` messages still stay in French. Only the messages generated by the postgres server are affected.

**Windows 10**

Comment: [lc_messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT) is responsible for server log language. However if OS supports.. Be sure that windows supports the value (en_US in your case)

Answer (score 1):

initdb and more generally all PostgreSQL command-line apps (psql, pg_dump, pg_restore...) use [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Translation-with-gettext.html) for translations, with translation files typically installed be the Windows installer under `INSTALLDIR\share\locale\lang[_region]` directories.

The default selection for the locale comes from the operating system, be it can be overriden with the environment variable `LC_MESSAGES`. To disable the translations, it can be set to `C`.

In `cmd.exe`:

```
set LC_MESSAGES=C
initdb [options]
```